# Change height of UIProgressView (Bar style) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, height, uiprogressview

I created a UIProgressView (bar style) in Swift 2.2 and would now like to alter its height. Some other posts suggested to use `CGAffineTransformScale` to change the height. However, for some reason this approach doesn't seem to work, as it does not have any effect on the height of the UIProgressView.

Below you will find my code:

```
let progressBar = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
progressBar.progress = 0.5
progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
progressBar.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(progressBar.transform, 1, 20)
self.navigationItem.titleView = progressBar
```

I appreciate your help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Try by setting the height constraint of UIProgressView.

Comment: What exactly the problem? is it that you can't see it? are you creating it programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subclass `UIProgressView`, and add a `height` property:

The result:

> [image]

```
import UIKit

class CustomProgressView: UIProgressView {

    var height:CGFloat = 1.0 
    // Do not change this default value, 
    // this will create a bug where your progressview wont work for the first x amount of pixel. 
    // x being the value you put here.

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let size:CGSize = CGSize.init(width: self.frame.size.width, height: height)

        return size
    }

}
```

In the `vc`, you initial the `customProgressvView`, and set the `height`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let progressBar = CustomProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
        progressBar.progress = 0.5
        progressBar.height = 10.0
        self.navigationItem.titleView = progressBar

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clean object-oriented solution!

I changed the width parameter equal to size.width in order to have the same width as normal. When I tried self.frame.size.width, the ProgressBar becomes much smaller (about half of the normal size). Does anyone have an explanation for this?